# Show that the Cauchy problem $x''=x|x|,x(0)=a,x^{\prime}(0)=b$ ,has a unique solution for all $a,b\in \Bbb R$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the Cauchy problem $x''=x|x|,x(0)=a,x^{\prime}(0)=b$,has a unique solution for all $a,b\in \Bbb R$. (The Problem is from *A text book on ordinary differential equation by Shair Ahmad and Antonio Ambrosetti*,exercise 4.3,pg:70)

**My attempt:**

I am using this theorem(given in book,page 69):

$\begin{cases} x^{(n)}=f(t,x',x'',...,x^{(n-1)})\\
             x(t_0)=\alpha_1,x'(t_0)=\alpha_2,...,x^{(n-1)}(t_0)=\alpha_n      \end{cases}$                                         (1)

*If $f:\Omega \to \Bbb R$ is continuous and locally lipschitzian with respect to $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),$ then (1) has a unique solution,defined in a suitable nbd of $t_0$.*($\Omega$ is an interval containing point $(t_0,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$)

(The function $f$ is called locally lipschitzian at  $(t_0,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \in \Omega$ with respect to $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ if $\exists$ a neighborhood $U \subset \Omega$ of $(t_0,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and a number $L>0$ such that, denoting by $|.|$ the euclidean norm in $\Bbb R^n$, one has

$|f(t,x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-f(t,z_1,z_2,...,z_n)|\leq L |(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)-(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)|$ for every$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n),(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) \in U$. )

clearly $f$ is continuous.therefore we will show that $f$is lipschitzian at point $(0,a,b)$.

To prove lipschitzian at point $(0,a,b)$ we have to show that $\exists$ a nbd U of $\Bbb R^3$ containing point$(0,a,b)$ and a number $L>0$ such that

$|f(t,x,x_1)-f(t,z,z_2)| \leq L||(x,x_1)-(z,z_1)||$   $\forall (t,x,x_1),(t,z,z_1) \in U$

here $||(x,x_1)-(z,z_1)||=\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(x_1-z_1)^2}$

Now $x|x|$ is differentiable everywhere on $\Bbb R$.therefore it is locally lipschitz on any finite interval of $\Bbb R$.
therefore we have (for finite interval)

$|x|x|-z|z||\leq L|x-z|$ for some number $L$.

Now

$|x|x|-z|z||\leq L|x-z| \leq L \sqrt{(x-z)^2+(x_1-z_1)^2}$

$\therefore$$|f(t,x,x_1)-f(t,z,z_2)| \leq L||(x,x_1)-(z,z_1)||$   $\forall (t,x,x_1),(t,z,z_1) \in U$ where $U$ is any nbd of finite radius of $\Bbb R^3$ which contains the point $(0,a,b)$

Hence given problem has a unique solution for all $a,b\in \Bbb R$.

I am confusing whether am I correct or not?If it is not correct then where am I making mistake?and how to solve this problem?Thank you in advance.